# MFP CLI 7.1 push error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli

I'm getting an error when I try to push my runtime to the MFP CLI server

version 7.1.0.00.20151219-1541

> install-WAR:
>   [configureapplicationserver] Logging output of task  to file /Users/hannade/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/configureApplicationServer_2015_12_24_09_39_49.log
>   [configureapplicationserver] WARNING: The Reports database is deprecated in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation since V7.0.0.
>   [configureapplicationserver] Use Operational Analytics instead.
>   [configureapplicationserver] See http://ibm.biz/knowctr#SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_overview.html
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war Error deploying WAR file to server.
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war Error: 
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war BUILD FAILED
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:413: Element  inside  inside : Cannot access database jdbc:derby:/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war Details: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT' with class loader AntClassLoader[/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar], see the next exception for details.
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war 
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war Total time: 1 second
>   mobilefirst-cli sill build-deploy-war 
>   mobilefirst-cli sill mfp_push-main project not valid: {"cmdInfo":{"debugLevel":"silly","cwd":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","rawArgs":{"remain":[],"cooked":["--dd"],"original":["--dd"]}},"deployables":[{"platform":"Common","platformId":"hybridCommonLegacy","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/apps/test","type":"application","environment":"common","applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","technology":"hybrid","structure":"Legacy","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/JSDataAdapter","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/deposit","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/depositHistory","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/depositsToReview","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/history","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/review","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"},{"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/test","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"}],"projectType":"MFP_LEGACY_PROJECT","projectPath":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","backendRuntime":{"path":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","localServerInfo":{"local":true,"protocol":"http","host":"localhost","port":10080,"login":"admin","password":"YWRtaW4=","wlpInstallDir":"/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server","wlpServerName":"worklight","jarDir":"/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/WorklightServer","version":"7.1.0.00.20151219-1535"},"serversDirectory":"/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server","name":"kmf"},"mobileFirstPath":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/mobilefirst"}
>   Error: Error deploying WAR file to server.
>   Error: 
>   BUILD FAILED
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:413: Element  inside  inside : Cannot access database jdbc:derby:/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT
>   Details: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT' with class loader AntClassLoader[/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar], see the next exception for details.

Total time: 1 second

mobilefirst-cli sill {"jse_shortmsg":"Error deploying WAR file to server.\nError: \nBUILD FAILED\n/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:413: Element  inside  inside : Cannot access database jdbc:derby:/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT\nDetails: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT' with class loader AntClassLoader[/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar], see the next exception for details.\n\nTotal time: 1 second\n","jse_summary":"Error deploying WAR file to server.\nError: \nBUILD FAILED\n/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:413: Element  inside  inside : Cannot access database jdbc:derby:/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT\nDetails: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT' with class loader AntClassLoader[/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar], see the next exception for details.\n\nTotal time: 1 second\n","message":"Error deploying WAR file to server.\nError: \nBUILD FAILED\n/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:413: Element  inside  inside : Cannot access database jdbc:derby:/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT\nDetails: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database '/Users/hannade/.ibm/mobilefirst/7.1.0.00.20151219-1535/server/derby/kmf/WRKLGHT' with class loader AntClassLoader[/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar], see the next exception for details.\n\nTotal time: 1 second\n"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"platform":"Common","platformId":"hybridCommonLegacy","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/apps/test","type":"application","environment":"common","applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","technology":"hybrid","structure":"Legacy","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/JSDataAdapter","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/deposit","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/depositHistory","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/depositsToReview","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/history","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/review","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
mobilefirst-cli sill could not determine status of the following deployablable: {"applicationDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","platformDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/adapters/test","mfpConfigDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf","archiveDirectory":"/Users/hannade/Developer/KMF/kmf/bin","type":"adapter","status":"APP_SOURCE_FOUND","technology":"hybrid","platform":"Adapter","structure":"Legacy","platformId":"hybridAdapterLegacy","debugLevel":"silly"} 
Error: Push has failed
mobilefirst-cli verb cli finish with mobilefirst push 
mobilefirst-cli verb code 0
macsupports-MacBook-Pro-8:kmf hannade$

Comment: once I hopped off my proxy network at work it worked fine, why is this, do i need to set proxies for mfp cli?

Comment: updated the error using the debug flag, this is still a problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell from the exception.

You can try again with the debug flag as it may tell more.
Alternatively you can open a PMR to have the development team further investigate it. As it it the *workaround* it not connect to the proxy at the same time. Sounds like a potential bug...